# Connecting two joists with a wooden piece to hang a projector screen

Tags: ceiling, joists, studs

I have a projector screen (45lbs) that I have to hang on the ceiling on it's two ends. However the joists on the two ends are not correctly positioned so I can't hang the projector screen where I want to hang it. So I went to the attic and found that there are two joists spaced 3 feet apart. The point where I want to hang the projector screen falls between the two joists. So I bought a 2x4 stud wood and now I want to connect that wood between two joists. However I don't have access to the side of the joists. I want to see if there are any flat metal connectors or something like that I can use to connect the joists using the stud wood. What's your recommendation?

Comment: [Toenailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toenailing)

Comment: Do you or do you not have attic access to the top of the studs?  If you want the wood to be flush with the existing joists, the joist hangars you're looking at should be fine.  If that particular shape can't be crammed in where you need, there are a wide variety of other stud bracket shapes available.  Another option if screwing in the joist hangars is super awkward is by using universal strut or even wood perpendicular across the existing studs and dropping all thread rod hangars from this cross member through the drywall.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing a toe nail and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Search for ceiling fan joist hangers - sound like that would be perfect for what you need.

Comment: But unfortunately the hole/hanger is too large for just suspending a support hook... Any other options?

Comment: Can this help? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-LUS-ZMAX-Galvanized-Face-Mount-Joist-Hanger-for-2x4-Nominal-Lumber-LUS24Z/100375190